# Two-Way lookup in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, lookup, two-way

So basically I have 2 DataFrames like this:

Table_1

| Apple | Banana | Orange | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2020 |
| 3 | 5 | 2 | 2021 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 2022 |

Table_2

| fruit | year |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2020 |
| Apple | 2021 |
| Apple | 2022 |
| Banana | 2020 |
| Banana | 2021 |
| Banana | 2022 |
| Orange | 2020 |
| Orange | 2021 |
| Orange | 2022 |

So I want to lookup the values for the fruits for Table_2 from the Table_1 based on the fruit name and the respective year.

The final outcome should look like this:

| fruit | year | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2020 | 1 |
| Apple | 2021 | 3 |
| Apple | 2022 | 7 |
| Banana | 2020 | 2 |
| Banana | 2021 | 5 |
| Banana | 2022 | 8 |
| Orange | 2020 | 4 |
| Orange | 2021 | 2 |
| Orange | 2022 | 9 |

In the Excel for an example one can do something like this:

```
=INDEX(Table1[[Apple]:[Orange]],MATCH([@year],Table1[Date],0),MATCH([@fruit],Table1[[#Headers],[Apple]:[Orange]],0))
```

But what is the way to do it in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can `melt` and `merge`:

```
out = (df2
   .merge(df1.rename(columns={'Date': 'year'})
              .melt('year', var_name='fruit', value_name='number'),
           how='left'
          )
)
```

output:

```
    fruit  year  number
0   Apple  2020       1
1   Apple  2021       3
2   Apple  2022       7
3  Banana  2020       2
4  Banana  2021       5
5  Banana  2022       8
6  Orange  2020       4
7  Orange  2021       2
8  Orange  2022       9
```